# which one is the best solutions a new activation function or customize own layer

Tags: deep-learning

when a new activation function is more suitable than the customize own layer? what is different of these? when we use from a new layer or new activation function.

we need model a fitness function, but we don't know what is the best solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my problem is a link prediction in social network and the page rank formula is used. Now we using deep learning method but we don't know what is the best the page rank in activation function or a new layer as page rank.

Comment: Please, provide more details. What is the input? What should be the output? What have you tried? [minimal reproducibility](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the input is social network graph. the output is a node that the node can be related. The link prediction is our problem like friend proposed .